# Limits on Dropbox API when calling from a single account

Tags: dropbox-api

I'm currently trying to make a website that allows users to host files, so I intend on buying a business Dropbox account for this purpose, generate an Access Token so the app don't go through OAuth authentication and internally serve and upload files to this single account.

Could it be done using a single Dropbox account? What are limits on calling from a single account. All access token logic would be hardcoded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Dropbox API does have a rate limiting system, but we don't have any specific numbers documented. It is only designed to prevent abuse though, and is accordingly very generous. Further, the limits operate on a per-user basis. That being the case, you generally don't need to worry about hitting it in normal use. The Dropbox API rate limiting system operates the same regardless of account type.

Also note that not all 429s or 503s indicate rate limiting, but in any case that you get a 429 or 503 the best practice is to retry the request, respecting the Retry-After header if given in the response, or using an exponential back-off, if not.

The API was designed with the intention that each user would link their own Dropbox account, in order to interact with their own files. However, it is technically possible to connect to just one account. The SDKs don't offer explicit support for it and we don't recommend doing so, for various technical and security reasons. Most of these concerns are allayed for server-side apps though.

So, if you did want to go this route, instead of kicking off the authorization flow, you would manually use an existing access token for your account and app, as you mentioned. (Just be careful not to revoke it, e.g. via https://www.dropbox.com/account/security .)

Comment: According to my understanding of the API limits, I will continue with developing with Dropbox API with single user access token